# Using CGI to run a script

Tags: html, ruby, cgi, webrick, rhtml

first time posting :)

I am doing an exercise in Ruby and i am a little stuck with the CGI method.

I used the HTML code below to send the form's input.

*Bit from HTML*

```
<form action="afficher.cgi" method="post">
    <label> Votre prenom </label> : <input type="text" name="prenom"/> <br>
    <label> Votre nom </label> : <input type="text" name="nom"/> <br>
    <label> Votre nom </label> : <input type="text" name="age"/> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Valider" />

</form>
```

When I submit the form, it goes to the .cgi page (executing the script) and works.

I was wondering if it possible to send the information to the .cgi and refresh the .rhtml and not going to the .cgi and be stuck there.

I tried to find a method or somethings to write in the .cgi that redirects to the .rhtml, but no clue. Is there a solution inside the .rhtml document ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to use javascript/ajax for that.

In your `form` tag, you should specify a function for the `onsubmit` field, instead of specifying a destination in `action`.

```
<form onsubmit="return submitForm(this)" id="form1" action="" method="post">
```

And then, in your javascript,

```
function submitForm()
{
    var xmlhttp= window.XMLHttpRequest ?
        new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // Here is the response
    }

    var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById("form1") );

    xmlhttp.open("POST","afficher.cgi", true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
    return false;
}
```